# interactive brokers api lagging behind tws when using 100 symbols

Tags: c++, interactive-brokers

I haven't been having this problem until I started putting more symbols up on my screeen.  I don't think it's a processing thing, my cpu has been fine and I'm not doing anything super super fancy anyways (just storing data to objects and writing to txt files every so often).

From day 1 with the api, I noticed that I had to put a sleep(1) in the while loop that constantly checks for messages, like so:

```
PosixTestClient client;
client.connect( host, port, clientId);  
while( client.isConnected()) {
        sleep(1);
        client.processMessages();
    }
```

If I don't have that sleep(1) there, it just crashes.  So I guess my first question is:  is that normal?  Or is something wrong with that?

And my next question is... any tips as to why there might be a lag in the api data as compared to the tws data?  I know there's a lag because as the data comes into the api, I'm storing it to strings and then every minute writing the data to text files.  Then I go back through my text files and compare it to the charts in tws... and I notice there's about a 2min lag!  I also notice it seems to get better (the lag goes away) after the first half hour of the trading day, when things are pretty active.

So... any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have subscribed Booster pack?
TWS API has 100 quotes limit, as well as API. You can buy additional 100 quotes for 30$.

> Quote Booster
>   Increase your allowance of simultaneous quotes windows by purchasing monthly Quote Booster packs at USD 30.00 per pack.
>
> Each booster pack provides 100 simultaneous Level I quotes. Booster Pack quotes are additional to your monthly quote allotment from all sources, including commissions.
>   Booster pack quotes are available for use in the desktop systems and in the API.
>   Once subscribed, quotes are available immediately and will display the next time you log into the system.
>   Data from a cancelled booster pack subscription remains available through the end of the current billing cycle.
>   Limit of 10 Quote Booster packs per account.

Answer (score 1):

So... with the help of the very helpful and friendly yahoo TWS API users group: https://groups.io/g/twsapi/messages

I was able to find the answer, which was simply:

reduce the sleep time!  Running it with no sleep in between the client.proccessMessages() would cause my cpu to run pretty high, but all I needed to really relax cpu was to just sleep for a milisecond... not a whole second.  Sleeping for a whole second was causing a lag in data (I suspect that IB ques the data and then 'sends' it to you when you call proccessMessages(), so you need to call that often enough to stay ahead of the tick data you are receiving!)

For anyone who wants to read it in more detail, here was the thread: https://groups.io/g/twsapi/topic/4702705#37186

Fingers crossed that it continues to work, but today I got good data on 100 high-volume tickers with no lag :)